# Can I use a variable created for a component with an on click event?

Tags: delphi

I have 56 panels, and I created a loop running through them, selecting a random panel. After a random panel is selected, I use `FindComponent()` with the name of the random panel, and assign a variable to the random panel. Now I have the random panel as a variable, and what I want to do is use the `OnClick` event with the variable, but I have trouble using it. I want to display a `ShowMessage()` once that panel has been clicked.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iRandomNum, iCharRandom, iCnt: integer;
  cChar: char;
  sPanelName: string;

begin
 
  Randomize;
  iRandomNum := Random(7 - 1 + 1) + 1;
  iCharRandom := Random(8 - 1 + 1) + 1;
  case iCharRandom of
    1:
      cChar := 'A';
    2:
      cChar := 'B';
    3:
      cChar := 'C';
    4:
      cChar := 'D';
    5:
      cChar := 'E';
    6:
      cChar := 'F';
    7:
      cChar := 'G';
    8:
      cChar := 'H';
  end;
  sPanelName := 'pnl' + cChar + IntToStr(iRandomNum);
  for iCnt := 1 to 56 do
  begin
    pnlCorrect := FindComponent(sPanelName) as TPanel;
  end;
  pnlCorrect.OnClick := showmessage('Correct panel');
end;
```

I tried to just display a `ShowMessage()` with the `OnClick` event of the variable, but it doesn’t work. I keep getting a runtime error.

---

**Edit:**

My new code is added below...

```
 procedure btnTest1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private

  procedure pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
{ Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.btnTest1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;

  function FindPanel(iChar, iNum: Integer): TPanel;
  var
    cChar: Char;
    sPanelName: string;
  begin
    cChar := Char(Ord('A') + iChar);
    sPanelName := 'pnl' + cChar + IntToStr(iNum);
    Result := FindComponent(sPanelName) as TPanel;
    redGameTest.Lines.Add(sPanelName);
  end;

begin
  // reset the OnClick events of the panels first...
  for i := 0 to 6 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 8 do
      FindPanel(i, j).OnClick := pnlWrongClick;
  end;

  // now, pick a random panel and assign its OnClick event...
  FindPanel(Random(8), Random(7) + 1).OnClick := pnlCorrectClick;

end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
  Randomize;
end;

...

procedure TForm1.pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Correct panel');
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Wrong panel');
end;
```

The Debugger Exception Notification says:

> Project PAT_P.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0062a218: write of address 0x00000124'.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please SHOW the actual code you are having trouble with, don't just DESCRIBE the code. Saying that something "doesn't work" says nothing useful about the actual problem you are actually having. Are you getting a compiler error? A runtime error? Behavior you are not expecting? Please be specific.  If I had to guess (and please, don't make people guess), you can probably solve your issue by using the event's `Sender` parameter, which points at the panel that is being clicked on.

Comment: Sorry @RemyLebeau, I added the code. Let me know if there is something else that I need to specify more.

Comment: Please don't re-write your question after answers are posted. If you have new information to share, it should be appended to the original question, not replace it. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @IanBoyd please don't edit someone else's question with code that isn't theirs, just because you don't agree with it. Besides, your edit had a bug in it anyway. I have rolled it back. If you have a change to suggest, you should post it in your own answer or comment instead.

Comment: Ok thanks, I’,m still learning all of this

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an expression like `showmessage('Correct panel');` directly to an `OnClick` event as you are trying to do.  Events expect to be assigned a class method instead.

Try something more like the following:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  published
    btnStart: TButton;
    PanelA1: TPanel;
    ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    ...
    procedure pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
    ... 
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;

  function FindPanel(iChar, iNum: Integer): TPanel;
  var
    cChar: Char;
    sPanelName: string;
  begin
    cChar := Char(Ord('A') + iChar);
    sPanelName := 'pnl' + cChar + IntToStr(iNum);
    Result := FindComponent(sPanelName) as TPanel;
  end;

begin
  // reset the OnClick events of the panels first...
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 7 do
      FindPanel(i, j).OnClick := pnlWrongClick;
  end;

  // now, pick a random panel and assign its OnClick event...
  FindPanel(Random(8), Random(7) + 1).OnClick := pnlCorrectClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Correct panel');
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Wrong panel');
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest putting all of the Panels into an array up front, then you don't have to search for any panels by name when the button is clicked, eg:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  published
    btnStart: TButton;
    PanelA1: TPanel;
    ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    Panels: array[0..55] of TPanel;
    procedure pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j, k: Integer;

  function FindPanel(iChar, iNum: Integer): TPanel;
  var
    cChar: Char;
    sPanelName: string;
  begin
    cChar := Char(Ord('A') + iChar);
    sPanelName := 'pnl' + cChar + IntToStr(iNum);
    Result := FindComponent(sPanelName) as TPanel;
  end;

begin
  Randomize;

  k := 0;
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 7 do
    begin
      Panels[k] := FindPanel(i, j);
      Inc(k);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  // reset the OnClick event of the panels first...
  for i := Low(Panels) to High(Panels) do
    Panels[i].OnClick := pnlWrongClick;

  // now, pick a random panel and assign its OnClick event...
  Panels[Random(56)].OnClick := pnlCorrectClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Correct panel');
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Wrong panel');
end;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249185/discussion-on-answer-by-remy-lebeau-can-i-use-a-variable-created-for-a-component).