# How to assign a variable to a randomly generated string?

Tags: delphi

This is a continuation of my previous question: [Can I use a variable created for a component with an on click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211980/)

I have the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTest1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  sCorrectpanel : string;

  function FindPanel(iChar, iNum: Integer): TPanel;
  var
    cChar: Char;
    sPanelName: string;
  begin
    cChar := Char(Ord('A') + iChar);
    sPanelName := 'pnl' + cChar + IntToStr(iNum);
    Result := FindComponent(sPanelName) as TPanel;
  end;

begin
  // reset the OnClick events of the panels first...
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 7 do
      FindPanel(i, j).OnClick := pnlWrongClick;
  end;

  // now, pick a random panel and assign its OnClick event...
  FindPanel(Random(8), Random(7) + 1).OnClick := pnlCorrectClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Correct panel');
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Wrong panel');
end;
```

The code randomly selects a panel, but I want to know what panel is selected by assigning the chosen panel's name to a variable.

Someone suggested to:

> simply declare your own variable to save the pointer that FindPanel() returns. Also, inside the OnClick handler, you can use the Sender parameter, too"

I just don't know how to do what he recommended, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a variable, you just need to assign a value to it. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTest1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  sCorrectPanel : string;
  pCurrentPanel : TPanel;

  function FindPanel(iChar, iNum: Integer): TPanel;
  var
    cChar: Char;
    sPanelName: string;
  begin
    cChar := Char(Ord('A') + iChar);
    sPanelName := 'pnl' + cChar + IntToStr(iNum);
    Result := FindComponent(sPanelName) as TPanel;
  end;

begin
  // reset the OnClick events of the panels first...
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 7 do
      FindPanel(i, j).OnClick := pnlWrongClick;
  end;

  // now, pick a random panel and assign its OnClick event...
  pCorrectPanel := FindPanel(Random(8), Random(7) + 1);
  pCorrectPanel.OnClick := pnlCorrectClick;

  sCorrectPanel := pCorrectPanel.Name; // <-- here
  // use sCorrectPanel as needed... 
end;

...

procedure TForm1.pnlCorrectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Correct panel: ' + TPanel(Sender).Name);
end;

procedure TForm1.pnlWrongClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Wrong panel: ' + TPanel(Sender).Name);
end;
```